# asp.net TextBox needs to be Red if not check. Using JS/jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

So, This might be simple for you guys! But I'm new to this and don't know how to move on with this..
If I click on my Button "Skicka" and I have not written in my TextBox or checked my CheckBox I need their borders to become Red and NOT give me my dialog... as it do now..

Appreciate your help! :)

Here is all my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="Uniqo.Pages.Contact" MasterPageFile="~/Layout/Main.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContactHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {          
            $(".ShowDialog").click(function () {
                var myTextboxes = $(".Validate");    //.Validate
                var isValid = true;

                for (var i = 0; i < myTextboxes.length; i++) {
                    var textValue = $(myTextboxes[i]).val();

                    if (textValue == "") {
                        $(myTextboxes[i]).css("border-color", "Red");
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }

                if (isValid == true) {
                    $(".messageSent").dialog();

                    $('.Validate').val(''); 
                    return false;
                }               
                return false;
            });
        })</script>
</asp:Content>



<asp:Content ID="ContactBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="messageSent" style="display:none;">
        Ditt meddelande är skickat! :)
    </div>

    <div id="ContactMainBody">
        <h2>Fyll i följande information för att skicka ditt meddelande.</h2>
        <p>
            Ditt namn: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="YourName" CssClass="Validate" runat="server" Width="250px" /><br /><br />

            Din E-mail: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" CssClass="Validate" runat="server" Width="250px" />
            <br /><br />

            Din fråga: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" CssClass="Validate"
                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" /><br />
        </p>

        <button id="ShowDialog" class="ShowDialog" style="height: 26px; cursor: pointer;">Skicka</button>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine! it's setting red borders! Do you expect anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be fine, but I believe you do not need that click event, instead you can solve your task using simple css:

```
.ShowDialog:checked {
    border-color: #FF0000;
}
```